# How to create svg file from data in csv file to create nameplates in a bash script

Tags: bash, csv, svg, command-line, inkscape

I have got a csv file with names, degrees and other data about several persons and a template svg file that shows me how the output should look. Now I should write a bash script that creates a new svg file with the data from the csv file that can be converted into a pdf and be printed to cut out the nameplates later. I have no idea how to do this and would be very happy about some proposals how to write my bash script and some hints what to mind doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using awk:

```awk
# begin by reading the whole first template file at once
BEGIN { RS = "^$" }
FILENAME==ARGV[1] { # NR=1 is the entire template file
  template = $0
  # very conveniently we can now setup RS FPAT etc to apply to the next line for the next file.
  RS = "\r\n"
  # quoted CSV fields pattern
  FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
}

FILENAME==ARGV[2] && NR==2 { # NR=2 is the first CSV line: column headers
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    headers[i] = $i
  }
}

FILENAME==ARGV[2] && NR>2 { # NR>2 is the rest of the CSV file records.
  # Strip quotes from quoted CSV values.
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    if (substr($i, 1, 1) == "\"") {
      $i = substr($i, 2, length($i) - 2)
    }
  }

  # Template Replacements
  result = template
  for (i = 1; i <= length(headers); i++) {
    gsub(headers[i], $i, result);
  }

  print result > "svg/" $1 ".svg"
}
```

Use like this:
`awk -f build.awk template.svg employees.csv`

Where template.svg is a template SVG file that contains the field names you want replaced. For example:

```xml
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue"/>
  <text id="svg_1" y="100" x="76" fill="#FFF">NAME</text>
 </g>
</svg>
```

This template would expect a CSV file that has a column header "NAME", but you can add as many fields in the template as you have in the CSV. The files would be output in a "svg/" directory, one file per line.

Answer (score 0):

Try Inkscape + the Generator extension:

Replace text and data to automatically generate files (as PDF, PNG, EPS, PS, JPG, SVG), based on an SVG template and a CSV file. Also available via apt in Debian and Ubuntu repositories.

http://wiki.colivre.net/Aurium/InkscapeGenerator

Example file set for testing and learning how to use:

https://inkscape.org/en/~Moini/%E2%98%85example-files-for-generator-extension

Comment: Updated version as of 2021: https://gitlab.com/Moini/nextgenerator (works with current Inkscape versions)